# Wrong coordinates after converting GML to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, c#, gml, osgeo

I'm using OSGeo.OGR (C#) library to perform GML to GeoJson conversion.
Parsing works perfect except extracting incorrect coordinates.
After conversion map objects appears in another place on the map. But [Aspose gml to geoJson converter](https://products.aspose.app/gis/conversion/gml-to-geojson)  outputs extracts/calculates correct coordinates ( belongs to Norway).

GML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <gml:FeatureCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" 
  xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss" xmlns:sc="http://www.interactive- 
  instruments.de/ShapeChange/AppInfo" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
  xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" 
  xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd">
      <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Envelope srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
        <gml:lowerCorner>371288.48000018 7262927.30999763</gml:lowerCorner>
       <gml:upperCorner>568674.61 7607606.54000031</gml:upperCorner>
    </gml:Envelope>
  </gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:featureMember>
<app:Lufthavn gml:id="id4c0c9f68-eb83-4931-b7ae-0b0ca561a81e">
  <app:identifikasjon>
    <app:Identifikasjon>
      <app:lokalId>10209c2b-8ea8-46b8-99d7-f79223b09fd3</app:lokalId>
      <app:navnerom>https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt</app:navnerom>
      <app:versjonId>20181115</app:versjonId>
    </app:Identifikasjon>
  </app:identifikasjon>
  <app:kommunenummer>1857</app:kommunenummer>
  <app:datauttaksdato>2021-06-24T04:00:11</app:datauttaksdato>
  <app:posisjon>
    <gml:Point gml:id="id4c0c9f68-eb83-4931-b7ae-0b0ca561a81e-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:pos>403582.480000027 7506119.62999981</gml:pos>
    </gml:Point>
  </app:posisjon>
  <app:lufthavnnavn>Værøy helikopterhavn</app:lufthavnnavn>
  <app:ICAOKode>ENVR</app:ICAOKode>
  <app:IATAKode>VRY</app:IATAKode>
  <app:høydeOverHavet>4.438</app:høydeOverHavet>
</app:Lufthavn>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<app:Lufthavn gml:id="id0b0bbcd1-9127-4fa3-8883-5662dc8fa62e">
  <app:identifikasjon>
    <app:Identifikasjon>
      <app:lokalId>ff739ca9-2e70-41a4-b56a-79b7014d1c02</app:lokalId>
      <app:navnerom>https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt</app:navnerom>
      <app:versjonId>20181115</app:versjonId>
    </app:Identifikasjon>
  </app:identifikasjon>
  <app:kommunenummer>1820</app:kommunenummer>
  <app:datauttaksdato>2021-06-24T04:00:11</app:datauttaksdato>
  <app:posisjon>
    <gml:Point gml:id="id0b0bbcd1-9127-4fa3-8883-5662dc8fa62e-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:pos>385178.19000007 7317855.14999908</gml:pos>
    </gml:Point>
  </app:posisjon>
  <app:lufthavnnavn>Sandnessjøen lufthavn, Stokka</app:lufthavnnavn>
  <app:ICAOKode>ENST</app:ICAOKode>
  <app:IATAKode>SSJ</app:IATAKode>
  <app:høydeOverHavet>17.463</app:høydeOverHavet>
</app:Lufthavn>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
<app:Lufthavn gml:id="id0d453b17-a461-4e34-845a-79db88dd2991">
  <app:identifikasjon>
    <app:Identifikasjon>
      <app:lokalId>db5eaa8e-7881-4e88-938a-4a8bcac5ea3f</app:lokalId>
      <app:navnerom>https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt</app:navnerom>
      <app:versjonId>20181115</app:versjonId>
    </app:Identifikasjon>
  </app:identifikasjon>
  <app:kommunenummer>1866</app:kommunenummer>
  <app:datauttaksdato>2021-06-24T04:00:11</app:datauttaksdato>
  <app:posisjon>
    <gml:Point gml:id="id0d453b17-a461-4e34-845a-79db88dd2991-0" srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25833" srsDimension="2">
      <gml:pos>501284.63 7607606.54000031</gml:pos>
    </gml:Point>
  </app:posisjon>
  <app:lufthavnnavn>Stokmarknes lufthavn, Skagen</app:lufthavnnavn>
  <app:ICAOKode>ENSK</app:ICAOKode>
  <app:IATAKode>SKN</app:IATAKode>
  <app:høydeOverHavet>3.99</app:høydeOverHavet>
</app:Lufthavn>
</gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

Parser code:

```
public GmlMapLayer[] ParseFile(string path)
   {
      GdalBase.ConfigureAll();

     if (!GdalBase.IsConfigured)
      {
      throw new ApplicationException("GdalBase cannot be configured properly.");
      }
     using (OSGeo.OGR.Driver drv = Ogr.GetDriverByName("GML"))
      {
      if (drv == null)
      {
          throw new ApplicationException("An appropriate GML driver not found.");
      }

      using (var ds = drv.Open(path, 0))
      {
          if (ds == null)
          {
          throw new ApplicationException("GML file has incorrect format or not found.");
          }

          var layerCount = ds.GetLayerCount();
          var mapLayers = new GmlMapLayer[layerCount];
          for (int i = 0; i < layerCount; i++)
          {
              Layer layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(i);
              var layerName = layer.GetName();
              Feature f;
              layer.ResetReading();

              List<string> features = new List<string>();

              while ((f = layer.GetNextFeature()) != null)
              {
                  Dictionary<string, string> properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                  var def = f.GetDefnRef();
                  var fieldCount = def.GetFieldCount();
                  for (int fieldIndex = 0; fieldIndex < fieldCount; fieldIndex++)
                  {
                      var field = def.GetFieldDefn(fieldIndex);
                      var fieldName = FixNorwegianEncoding(field.GetNameRef());
                      var fieldValue = f.GetFieldAsString(fieldIndex);
                      properties.Add(fieldName, fieldValue);
                  }
                  

                  var propertiesString = properties.ToJsonString();
                  var geom = f.GetGeometryRef();
                  var newSP = new OSGeo.OSR.SpatialReference(null);
                  newSP.SetWellKnownGeogCS("EPSG:4326");
                 
                  geom = geom.MakeValid();
                  geom.TransformTo(newSP);

                  var geometryJson = geom.ExportToJson(new string[0]);
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(geometryJson))
                  {
                      features.Add($"{{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{propertiesString},\"geometry\":{geometryJson}}}");
                  }
              }

              var featuresString = string.Join(",", features);
              var geoJSON = $"{{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"name\":\"{layerName}\", \"features\":[{featuresString}]}}";
              var mapLayer = new GmlMapLayer 
              { 
                  Name = layerName, 
                  OverlayCollection = geoJSON 
              };
              mapLayers[i] = mapLayer;
          }

          return mapLayers;
      }
  }
}
```

```
{
 "type": "FeatureCollection",
 "name": "Lufthavn",
 "features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
     "properties": {
      "gml_id": "id4c0c9f68-eb83-4931-b7ae-0b0ca561a81e",
      "lokalId": "10209c2b-8ea8-46b8-99d7-f79223b09fd3",
      "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt",
    "versjonId": "20181115",
    "kommunenummer": "1857",
    "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11",
    "lufthavnnavn": "Værøy helikopterhavn",
    "icaoKode": "ENVR",
    "iataKode": "VRY",
    "hÃ¸ydeOverHavet": "4.438"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      12.727040456279207,
      67.654549594804607,
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gml_id": "id0b0bbcd1-9127-4fa3-8883-5662dc8fa62e",
    "lokalId": "ff739ca9-2e70-41a4-b56a-79b7014d1c02",
    "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt",
    "versjonId": "20181115",
    "kommunenummer": "1820",
    "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11",
    "lufthavnnavn": "Sandnessjøen lufthavn, Stokka",
    "icaoKode": "ENST",
    "iataKode": "SSJ",
    "hÃ¸ydeOverHavet": "17.463"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      2.130202148445286,
      67.103282733197915
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "gml_id": "id0d453b17-a461-4e34-845a-79db88dd2991",
    "lokalId": "db5eaa8e-7881-4e88-938a-4a8bcac5ea3f",
    "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt",
    "versjonId": "20181115",
    "kommunenummer": "1866",
    "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11",
    "lufthavnnavn": "Stokmarknes lufthavn, Skagen",
    "icaoKode": "ENSK",
    "iataKode": "SKN",
    "hÃ¸ydeOverHavet": "3.99"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      2.671688028890271,
      68.700998863765506
    ]
  }
}
```

]
}

Comment: Where do the objects appear? `ogr2ogr -f geojson -t_srs epsg:4326 norge.json norge_fixed.gml` yields `"type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "id4c0c9f68-eb83-4931-b7ae-0b0ca561a81e", "lokalId": "10209c2b-8ea8-46b8-99d7-f79223b09fd3", "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt", "versjonId": 20181115, "kommunenummer": 1857, "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11", "lufthavnnavn": "Varoy helikopterhavn", "ICAOKode": "ENVR", "IATAKode": "VRY", "hoydeOverHavet": 4.438 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.727040456279207, 67.654549594804607 ] } }`

Comment: with your Json, Object appears on Arabian sea, But it should be on Norway.

Comment: In GeoJSON the coordinates are in longitude-latitude order, so 12.72 degrees E, 67.6 degrees N.

Comment: Actually I test the output with this site https://geojson.io/#map=5/13.347/65.039

Comment: you mean that I need an additional logic to order long/lat? And I don't know how you converted the gml. I use C# Library.

Comment: I used https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html. The exact command is in my comment. I fixed some Norwegian letters in the norge_fixed.gml file but otherwise it is copied from your question. The URL of geojson.io fooled you, in the URL the coordinates are in zoom/latitude/longitude order but in GeoJSON the coordinates appear in longitude/latitude order.

Comment: @user30184 added GeoJson output of my parser. object are located on indian sea )

Comment: Object with `"Point","coordinates": [2.130202148445286,67.10328273319791]` is located on Norwegian Sea, between Norway and Iceland. As I told, the order is lon-lat in GeoJSON. But you do have wrong coordinate values still, you should get `12.473464697204886, 65.96081704848379` for Sandnessjøen lufthavn.

Comment: @user30184 yes you are right. the order is lon-lat. So it means that I should manually write a logic to change the order? or there is a code to do so ?

Comment: See my edited answer. You seem to pass the source coordinates in wrong order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop this into https://geojson.io/ and you can see that GDAL ogr2ogr with command `ogr2ogr -f geojson -t_srs epsg:4326 norge.json norge_fixed.gml`makes the right result.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Lufthavn",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "id4c0c9f68-eb83-4931-b7ae-0b0ca561a81e", "lokalId": "10209c2b-8ea8-46b8-99d7-f79223b09fd3", "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt", "versjonId": 20181115, "kommunenummer": 1857, "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11", "lufthavnnavn": "Varoy helikopterhavn", "ICAOKode": "ENVR", "IATAKode": "VRY", "hoydeOverHavet": 4.438 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.727040456279207, 67.654549594804607 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "id0b0bbcd1-9127-4fa3-8883-5662dc8fa62e", "lokalId": "ff739ca9-2e70-41a4-b56a-79b7014d1c02", "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt", "versjonId": 20181115, "kommunenummer": 1820, "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11", "lufthavnnavn": "Sandnessjoen lufthavn, Stokka", "ICAOKode": "ENST", "IATAKode": "SSJ", "hoydeOverHavet": 17.463 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12.473464697204886, 65.96081704848379 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "gml_id": "id0d453b17-a461-4e34-845a-79db88dd2991", "lokalId": "db5eaa8e-7881-4e88-938a-4a8bcac5ea3f", "navnerom": "https://data.geonorge.no/sosi/samferdsel/lufthavn_punkt", "versjonId": 20181115, "kommunenummer": 1866, "datauttaksdato": "2021-06-24T04:00:11", "lufthavnnavn": "Stokmarknes lufthavn, Skagen", "ICAOKode": "ENSK", "IATAKode": "SKN", "hoydeOverHavet": 3.99 }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 15.031520801165499, 68.580670821003068 ] } }
]
}
```

You probably did something wrong with the source coordinates. See:

```
gdaltransform -s_srs epsg:25833 -t_srs epsg:4326
Enter X Y [Z [T]] values separated by space, and press Return.
385178.19000007 7317855.14999908
12.4734646972049 65.9608170484838 0
7317855.14999908 385178.19000007
67.1032827331979 2.13020214844529 0
```

First example is taking EPSG:25833 coordinates correctly as easting-northing and gives the correct lon-lat coordinates. In the second example the EPSG:25833 coordinates are flipped (north coordinate used as easting) and the result shows the same wrong coordinates that you got with your code.

Comment: thank you. I added logic to re-order lat-lon for points. and now objects are on right place.

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON uses Lon-Lat, so your source probably does Lat-Lon.